# MySQL: error collation "in use" and table could not be loaded

Tags: mysql, wordpress, innodb, cpanel, collation

I have my `VPS` installed `cPanel`. Today it suddenly not work, all of `Wordpress` websites on `VPS` show the error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

and auto redirect to `wp-admin/install.php`.
I log in to phpmyadmin then see some tables have **collation "in use"** (not **"utf8_general_ci"** such as normally). Can't be loaded because of error:

```
#1286 - Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'".
```

So how to fix this error?
Thanks for help me!

Comment: 1. There is no question in your post, just a series of errors. 2. If everything was working yesterday, and today it does not work any longer, then probably you should ask your provider / sysadmin what they have done to your site.

Comment: Sorry my English is not good. But it's my VPS so the provider doesn't support. I installed it myself. Now there are some errors above but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, this issue raised up because your innoDB got corrupted and all your databases using innoDB tables are showing in-use.

To fix this issue you need to follow the below steps

To get 100% clean tablespace you need to start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=4, take mysqldump and restore it on a fresh instance of InnoDB (by fresh I mean you have to delete ibdata1, and all databases directories).

UPDATE:

At this point MySQL is started with innodb_force_recovery=x (x != 0)

Take dump of all databases:

## mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -A > alldb.sql

Check where MySQL keeps its files(in my case it's /var/lib/mysql/):

## mysql -NBe "SELECT @@datadir"

/var/lib/mysql/
Stop MySQL

## mysqladmin shut

Move old MySQL files to safe place

## mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old

Create new system database

## mkdir /var/lib/mysql

## mysql_install_db

Start MySQL

## /etc/init.d/mysql start

Restore the dump

## mysql < alldb.sql

Restore may take long time if the database is big.

Another trick may work in that case. Run ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE INNODB on each InnoDB table. It will rebuild all InnoDB indexes and thus the errors will go away.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Another solution to this is restoring the databases from backup.

For this first you need to remove ibdata1 file

cd /var/lib/mysql

rm -f ibdata1

Then restore all the databases one by one using below command

mysql -u username -p databasename < backupfile.sql

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: The first cmd mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -A > alldb.sql shows the error:
Couldn't execute 'show fields from 'wp_1_department_hours'': Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_2128_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13). What's the error and how can I fix it? Thanks for help!

Comment: do you have backup for the databases?